# NullPointerException when registering a new command in main class

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I want to create a new command in a minecraft plugin im currenly developing.
it should give a player an item. I registered the command in my main class and in the plugin.yml but when the server loads the plugin, it always throws a NullPointerException.

i would really appreciate any help

Thanks!

Here is my main class:

```
package dungeonsremake.dungeonsremake;

import dungeonsremake.dungeonsremake.commands.GiveCustomItem;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
    
            this.getCommand("item").setExecutor(new GiveCustomItem());
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Shutting down Plugin");
    }

}
```

And here is my Command class:

```
package dungeonsremake.dungeonsremake.commands;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class GiveCustomItem implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        System.out.println("activated");
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            return true;
        }
        Player player = (Player) sender;
    
        if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            ItemStack fot = new ItemStack(Material.LEGACY_RED_ROSE);
            fot.setAmount(1);
            player.getInventory().addItem(fot);
            return true;
        }
    
        return true;
    
    }

}
```

and here my plugin.yml:

```
name: DungeonsRemake
main: dungeonsremake.dungeonsremake.Main
version: 1.0

commands:
item:
usage: /<command>
description: gives the player a custom item.
aliases: [giveitem, item, customitem, ci, gci]
```

error message:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.setExecutor(org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor)" because the return value of "dungeonsremake.dungeonsremake.Main.getCommand(String)" is null
    at dungeonsremake.dungeonsremake.Main.onEnable(Main.java:15) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot-api-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:342) ~[spigot-api-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-api-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_18_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:517) ~[spigot-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3465-Spigot-ffceeae-3ec79a2]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_18_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:431) ~[spigot-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3465-Spigot-ffceeae-3ec79a2]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld0(MinecraftServer.java:612) ~[spigot-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3465-Spigot-ffceeae-3ec79a2]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadLevel(MinecraftServer.java:414) ~[spigot-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3465-Spigot-ffceeae-3ec79a2]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.e(DedicatedServer.java:263) ~[spigot-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3465-Spigot-ffceeae-3ec79a2]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1007) ~[spigot-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3465-Spigot-ffceeae-3ec79a2]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:304) ~[spigot-1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3465-Spigot-ffceeae-3ec79a2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error?

Comment: sure, i edited the message

Comment: Is the indentation of your plugin.yml correct to what you're actually using?

Comment: Since `onEnable` only has one line of code, it stands to reason that `getCommand("item")` is returning null.

Comment: do you mean the reference to the main class? i think so i can add a screenshot of my project tree.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g85N7.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/plugin/java/JavaPlugin.html#getCommand(java.lang.String)):

> Commands need to be registered in the PluginDescriptionFile to exist at runtime.

The reason it cannot find your `item` command is because the indentation in yaml matters. If your IDE doesn't have a built-in parser, you can use an online one like [this](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) to see the issue.

```yaml
commands:
  item:
   usage: /<command>
   description: gives the player a custom item.
   aliases: [giveitem, item, customitem, ci, gci]
```

That should be the correct indentation.

Comment: no, it still isn't working still the same error message. im really sorry.

Comment: ah now i got it working thank you very much!